# Односвязный список C++

Tags: классы, указатели, структуры, односвязный-список

Всех приветствую! Есть несколько недопониманий касаемо кода программы. Знаю, что тут не любят подобные вопросы, но все же. 1) Насколько я понимаю все указатели типа Node* имеют поля данной структуры, тогда в 22 строчке (tmp = nd) мы присваиваем указателю tmp только ссылку или все поля tmp становятся равными полям nd + присваивание самой ссылки? 2) Не совсем понимаю как я связываю узлы между с собой, если меняется только tmp? 3) Откуда у tmp значение в поле val? Значения полей указателей зависят от адреса, который они хранят?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Node {
    Node* NextNode = nullptr;
    int val = 0;
    
};

struct forward_list {
    Node* start;
    Node* tmp;
    forward_list() : start (nullptr) , tmp (nullptr)
    {}

    void push(int val) {
        Node* nd = new Node;
        nd->val = val;
        nd->NextNode = nullptr; 
        if (start == nullptr) {
            start = nd;
            tmp = nd;
            return;
        }
        tmp->NextNode = nd;
        tmp = tmp->NextNode;
    }
    void printList()
    {
        Node* tmp = start;
        while (tmp!= NULL)
        {
            std :: cout << tmp->val << std :: endl;
            tmp = tmp->NextNode;
        }
    }
};
    


int main()
{
    
    using namespace std;
    
    forward_list list;
    list.push(1);
    list.push(2);
    list.push(3);
    list.printList();
    
}
```

Comment: `"Насколько я понимаю все указатели типа Node* имеют поля данной структуры"`  -- не правильно понимаете. Тип `Node *` это указатель, т.е. адрес памяти (почти во всех компах это просто целое число). По этому адресу в  памяти лежит структура `Node`. Вот у нее есть поля. Поля структуры forward_list  start и tmp (кстати, по смыслу ему лучше подошло бы имя last) это тоже указатели. У них самих никаких полей нет, при присваивании меняется только значение указателя (адрес памяти).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Не согласен только по поводу полей указателей. У указателя tmp мы меняем поле NextNode. Разве не так?

Comment: Не так. Мы меняем поле `NextNode` структуры типа `Node`, *которая адресуется* указателем `tmp`. Поле -- это часть памяти, занимаемой структурой, а не указателем.

Comment: То есть мы меняем поле структуры, а не объекта, и тогда каждый новый экземпляр класса будет иметь в *NextNode тот же адрес, который указан в поле структуры? Попрошу у вас совета, если вам не сложно, не могли бы подсказать в какой области у меня пробелы? Я не до конца понимаю как работают структуры или указатели? А может и то, и то?

Comment: Вы слишком серьезно относитесь к терминологии, в повседневном употреблении все сильно зависит от контекста, т.е. структура, класс, объект это в общем-то одно и то же и это слово может означать как экземпляр, так и описание -) При доступе по указателю мы меняем содержимое памяти   ранее созданного экземпляра объекта (или структуры). А поля каждого нового экземпляра `Node` инициализируются значениями из описания этой структуры (вот у вас в тексте -- `struct Node { Node* NextNode = nullptr; int val = 0;};`)